# camera_prosilica: setting whitebalance_red/blue fails

Tags: ros, dynamic-reconfigure, prosilica-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there

I've a fresh install of ROS (desktop-full) with camera drivers. I successfully can stream from a Prosilica GC655C and set/get parameters with, e.g., dynamic_reconfigure. The only parameter I can't set is 'whitebalance_red' and 'whitebalance_blue'. Of course, 'auto_whitebalance' is set to off.

setting the whitebalance values directly with the SampleViewer it works, but not trough ROS. Even setting the parameter by rosparam doesn't work.

Do you have an idea how to make it work?

Best,
Dani

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10864/camera_prosilica:-setting-whitebalance_red/blue-fails/) by [Daniel Eberli](https://answers.ros.org/users/940/daniel-eberli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2011-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the solution to the problem:

in the prosilica library (prosilica.cpp) in function `Camera::setWhiteBalance` the test, whether manual whitebalance is available

`PvAttrIsAvailable(handle_, "WhitebalValueBlue")`

returns 0 (ePvErrSuccess) if manual whitebalance for blue is available. since the whitebal check is

`if (isauto == Manual && PvAttrIsAvailable(handle_, "WhitebalValueBlue"))`

it will FAIL if the `PvAttrIsAvailable` returns `ePvErrSuccess`.

`if (isauto == Manual && ePvErrSuccess == PvAttrIsAvailable(handle_, "WhitebalValueBlue"))`

will solve the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Eberli](https://answers.ros.org/users/940/daniel-eberli/) with karma: 91 on 2011-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) on 2011-08-11**:
Thanks Daniel. Could you please open a ticket (go to http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_drivers and click the "report bugs" link at the bottom) to make sure this issue doesn't get lost.